# Align `case`'s coditions inside `subnumcases`

Tags: alignment, cases

I have a PDE with an initial contition:

[image]

**I think it would be more beautiful if all conditions (the orange with the yellows) were aligned.**

I wrote this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
    
        \begin{subnumcases}{}
        u_t+3u^2u_x=0,& $ x\in\mathbb{R}, t>0 $ \label{erg2:burgers}
        \\
        u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
            3,& x\leq 1 \\
            2, & 1<x<2 \\
            1,& x\geq 2 
        \end{cases} \label{erg2:burgersii}
    \end{subnumcases}
    
\end{document}
```

**How can I improve my code?**

Thanks, in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a good idea: the side conditions belong to different parts and mean very different things.

Anyway, I'd use `empheq` rather than `subnumcases`, because the former works better along with other packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$\displaystyle u_t+3u^2u_x=0,$}%
\settowidth{\dimen2}{$\displaystyle
   u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 3, \\ 2, \\ 1, \end{cases}$}%
\addtolength{\dimen0}{-\dimen2}%
\newcommand{\SEP}{\quad\hspace*{\dimen0}}%
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  & u_t+3u^2u_x=0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}, t>0 \label{erg2:burgers} \\
  & u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
             3, \SEP & x\leq 1 \\
             2, \SEP & 1<x<2 \\
             1, \SEP & x\geq 2
        \end{cases} \label{erg2:burgersii}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to measure the difference of the widths and to manually add the required space.

[image]

With no forced alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  & u_t+3u^2u_x=0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}, t>0 \label{erg2:burgers} \\[2ex]
  & u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
             3, & x\leq 1 \\
             2, & 1<x<2 \\
             1, & x\geq 2
        \end{cases} \label{erg2:burgersii}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem solved! Have a nice day! PS: I believe you are right about the mathematical part... Maybe it's not a good idea to write it like this.